# Underscore.js + Visual Studio Code = Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, underscore.js

I'm trying to use underscore.js lib in Visual Studio code. Underscore is installed by using:

```
npm install underscore
```

My code is:

```
import {_} from "./node_modules/underscore/underscore.js";
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
var myFunction = function(element, index, list) {
  console.log(`Element : ${element}, Index : ${index}, Element found by index : ${list[index]}`);
_.each(arr1,myFunction);
```

Intellisense shows everything correctly, but when I debug, I'm getting

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.
Tnx for help.

Comment: Where’s the `}` for the function? Also, make sure your IDE is set up with ES6 support and your script is a module script.

Comment: @Xufox } wasn't copied, sorry. IDE is set up (I'm using VS Code, and target is es6), but not sure what do you mean for setting my script to be module script

Answer (score 0):

This syntax `import {_}` (ES Module style) from will only work with the new module system in node. The thing you are importing from has to be in a .mjs file.

You can probably do what you want by doing (CommonJS style):

```
const {_} = require("./node_modules/underscore/underscore.js");
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
var myFunction = function(element, index, list) {
  console.log(`Element : ${element}, Index : ${index}, Element found by index : ${list[index]}`);
_.each(arr1,myFunction);
```

If you don't like this then look into TypeScript or Webpack, or something else that will polyfill the ES module syntax.